# Features in Kubernetes but not in Swarm

Tags: kubernetes, docker-swarm

I've been watching some courses about both Docker Swarm and Kubernetes online - both in the courses and general opinion online seems to agree and suggest that Kubernetes although having a steeper learning curve, it is however more powerful. Having tried to search online I have however not come to any sort of list of features supported in Kubernetes but not in Swarm with the exception of Autoscaling.

I was just wondering if there are any experts out there who have maybe worked with both or simply have knowledge and can maybe help answering the question of "how is exactly Kubernetes more powerful than Swarm"? (excluding Autoscaling)

Just to be clear, am not asking for an exhaustive list of features, it's just that all the comparisons I've seen so far are relatively vague and the autoscaling feature although nice, might not applicable for some projects. So I was just wondering what other major features are there that is supported in one but not in other

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone with more experience can correct me if I'm wrong, but from my experience is that for the majority of the projects, both would provide the needed functionalities

Docker Swarm was only included with Docker since version 1.12 and that came out in 2016, whereas Kubernetes came out back in 2014. This means that a lot of the user base has already learned to use Kubernetes and belongs to an growing community, so why switch to Swarm ?

Because of the complexity of setting up and managing k8s, a lot of online cloud services started selling support for managing k8s which in turn created a lot of buzz around k8s.

Finally, one of the reason Swarm is simple to use and confogure is because it's opinionated, it's great if you want the behaviour provided however if for whatever reason you want to do something different then it might not even be possible